# Hiding Password in Electron Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron Application that needs to connect to an external PouchDB / CouchDB and a FTP-Server to retrieve some data. So in my Code I use

```
remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://my-Couch-User:my-Couch-Password@123.456.789.225:5984/myDB');
ftp.connect({host: ServerIPAddress), user: 'my-FTP-user', password: 'my-FTP-Password'});
```

I'm not working with highly confidential data, but having my passwords for external servers disclosed in such an easy readable form gives me the goosebumps.

Does anybody have an Idea how to at least hide them a little bit? (I know there is no way of really securing them under JavaScript)

Comment: Obscurity is not a valid security practice

Comment: But Electron leaves me with not a lot of choice regarding security. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the confidential data in environment variables and access them via `process.env.FTP_USERNAME` and `process.env.FTP_PASSWORD`, for example.

Passwords or tokens really shouldn't be hardcoded and readable.

If you have a lot of configuration values, credentials or tokens, then you can consider using dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or something similar.

*Edit*

Now that we learned about the OP requirements with his comments below this answer...

- It is not possible to hide passwords in any application. It will always be possible to extract them.
- Consider changing the server side code so that your applications don't talk with the FTP server directly but with a proxy where credentials are not required. The proxy then talks to the FTP server and the credentials will not be exposed.
- Consider using a system that provides access via tokens in addition to credentials. You could ask users to login with their personal credentials and the system could generate and send personal access tokens for the server.

Comment: Not following this – how are environment variables  set in a distributed app? (I understand how to set them in the dev environment)

Comment: The variables are not set *in* the app but on the system (the environment) that host the server. Hosting providers (like heroku) offer some UI to set them. The advantage of the `.env` file approach is that you can upload tho code to a repository and keep your secrets separate.

Comment: I never worked with environment variables... So the Idea is - if I understood it right - to store those values on a Server somewhere, and fetch them from there. That would be a nice idea, but the whole app runs offline. I do not have Internet connection when using the application. CouchDb and FTP are set up locally on a machine.

Comment: Not on *a* server, on your machine. Are you on windows? Open the "Edit environment variables for your account" dialog (Win+S, then type env, you'll see it) and add the key/value pairs with your secrets there.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting this. The OP seems to be asking about storing passwords in a **distributed Electron application** – so how do .env variables work for the **end user**? The end user will not even **know** the password to the server.

Comment: @Andreas Dolk Now a get the Idea. Thanks. No as spring pointed out, that cannot work. I have about 20 Machines that connect to the remote DB and FTP server on another computer. If I put the passwords on a central computer in my LAN, how are those remote clients gonna fetch them? I'd have to store them  on every client computer, which is of course not possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to have them on the code and you don't want users to login with their own credentials, then I can only think of either having them on a separate file that compiles the info or do a request to a server that generates session data for the app.

But people with a bit of knowledge would still have ways to get the info in both cases.